# Routing Static Files Using Flask

Tags: python, flask

So I'm going to go out and get it out of the way that I know this is probably a terrible way of doing serving static files for my website. I've come across a lot of other threads (that haven't quite solved my problem) that alluded to the fact that I should use a webserver like apache to serve static files. I've been doing that thus far for my static website but I mostly just wanted to mess around with it this way for development purposes while I learn Flask and add its functionality to the website.

So basically what's been causing me trouble is I want to serve all my static files(JS, CSS, etc.) using Flask and also route all my static webpages using flask as well (just for the time being, so I can run my app without apache and still load all of the links). My app setup is I have an 'app.py' with all my code and a 'static' directory for all my static files and a 'templates' folder for all my webpages

This is my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

# Create the application object
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

# Routes to path
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Routes to specific file, want to route all my pages instead
@app.route('/work.html')
def work():
    return render_template('work.html')

#Route methods for other webpages

# Serves static files
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)

# Start the server 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, there's a few notable problems with this code but unfortunately, this is best I could get it to run properly. For one, I've been reading a lot that 'send_from_directory' instead of 'send_static_file' is the proper way to send static files in Flask but I couldn't quite get that to work. But my main concern for the time being is that I can't route all my static webpages this way (and I would have thought that 'static_file' would have done this, in addition to serving all my JS, CSS, etc.); as it stands I only can route my webpages by creating a seperate function in 'app.py' for every webpage which seems terribly inefficent. So yeah, if there's a few lines in my code I need to change, I would be very grateful for being pointed in right direction!

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem as asked, but flask (and wsgi in general) is pretty slow for serving static files. I've found it's far faster to serve static files via nginx and proxy_pass all other requests into the wsgi process.

Comment: In development you can put your static files in a folder named `static` and link to them in your templates using `url_for('static', filename='style.css')` and so on for all your static files. [Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files).