# Flask unable to resolve static files

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to write a simple API using Flask. I am following Miguel Grinberg's [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask).

I have a use-case where I am trying to serve a static page. I am unable to serve the static webpage.

Here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sample/application/', methods=['GET'])
def static_website():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And following is my directory layout:

```
flask_application/
    - app.py
    - static/
        - index.html
        - cs/
            - app.css
            - bootstrap.css
        - js/
            - jquery.js
        - images/
            - logo.png
```

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I have gone through the following posts and it has not resolved my issue.

- [Unable to serve css, js and image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578330/flask-how-to-serve-static-html)
- [No response + question for templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413111/routing-static-files-using-flask)
- [Again related to templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772884/css-problems-with-flask-web-app)

There are other questions but no ones gives a concrete solution to resolve css, js files in static pages.

The server created by Flask is unable to pickup the js, css files.

Also, I am avoiding templating because this the only use-case I have and I am pretty sure, I am not going to add any other pages or make it more complex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42466734/1632479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template needs to be in a folder called `templates`. So the correct solution should be

```
flask_application/
   - templates/
     - index.html
```

You can read the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for the `render_template` method.

Comment: The css and js files need to be under static folder only?

Comment: Yeah, it's only the html templates that should be in the templates folder. All other files that you're serving should be in the static directory. 

There might be settings to customize this too though. But that's the general layout.

Comment: @amriteya, But if you're after a completely static website, why are you not using something like pelican? Is there a reason to use flask?

Comment: My page is still showing vanilla html without any style. The css, js files are not getting picked up.

Comment: You'll have to add the template itself so I can see the code for that.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about renderung a template, you can just send the static file on your route. This way you can just leave everything in the `static` directory.

`app.send_static_file('index.html')`

Just remember the rest of the assets will need to be referenced as `/static/<asset>`, ie  `<script src="/static/js/jquery.js></script>`